# How are "active" answers sorted?

Tags: discussion, sorting

What is the algorithm used by which SE sorts answers by "active"? How do number of votes, creation timestamp, and updated timestamp factor into the algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

Active answers are sorted chronologically by latest activity - either answering or editing. If you look through the active tab, you'll see something like:

> modified 40 secs ago
>
> modified 50 secs ago
>
> modified 1 min ago
>
> modified 9 mins ago
>
> modified 17 mins ago

(Unfortunately all of these are currently modifications, but if someone had asked a question, you would see `asked N [units] ago`.)

In fact, the timer is a link to the most recent activity. If you click on the time, it will take you to the reason for the activity.